# Using script tag as CSS condition for declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to make an extension that only runs on pages that have a certain script present but I've noticed that trying to do this through the `chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher` doesn't work. Is there a way around this?

I've tried the following just using a simple selector just to narrow down what was the issue but I don't think script tags are matched full stop. I'm wondering whether tags that don't appear in the body or aren't visible won't be matched.

```
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
          conditions: [
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
              css: ['script'],
            }),

          ],
              actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
      });
```

The button should have been greyed out on pages that don't have any script tags and in colour on those that do but instead it stays greyed out. I couldn't find any documentation to support my theory on which tags weren't supported and which were. Just wondering whether anyone has any insight on this. I *think* that I can still find this information out through  message passing from the content script but I don't think that will let me grey the icon out on pages it shouldn't run.

Comment: As the documentation says declarativeContent won't process elements with display:none so it can't match scripts.

Comment: @wOxxOm Right you are, I did miss that bit.